PHP Scandir() function works once then returns an error after
Basically, scandir() works once when the page loads but after interacting with a load function or changing the div contents to another PHP file it returns warnings and errors. Here are the simplified code snippets in question.
I'd like to know why this happens because in a previous part of the system where I had this exact code, it never returned this type of error before and the difference was that the previous one had the code inside a function.
manfile.php
require_once 'scanfiles.php';

<label>Folder Loc:</label>
<select name="" id="">
  <?php
    foreach ($dir as $dira){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $dira;?>"><?php echo $dira;?></option> <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>

scanfiles.php
$directs = scandir("uploads");
unset($directs[array_search('.', $directs, true)]);
unset($directs[array_search('..', $directs, true)]);
$dir = array("uploads");

foreach($directs as $direc){
    if(is_dir('uploads/' . $direc)) {
        array_push($dir, $direc);
    }
}

The error returning after interacting with the page consists of:

The output that works only once is correct:


Very unclear what is going on. You'll need to give more of an explanation, what "but after interacting with a load function or changing the div contents to another PHP file" actually means. We don't know how your site works.

I see, well the specific part of the system that contains this query is the "updating of files". It is located in the admin page wherein it also shares the page with multiple PHP pages and when I do interact with those elements that will transfer me to those said pages then it will return that error instantly and not follow through with loading the PHP file. I wanted to use scandir() to display all folders available for the admin if they wish to move the file to that directory.

All I can tell from that so far, is that you apparently have a problem with executing this in PHP files located in different folders, so that the relative path uploads doesn't resolve to the correct file system path. Maybe specify it absolute then, perhaps utilizing $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

@CBroe, using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] worked like a charm. Unfortunately, a new issue arouse and that is the foreach loop only executes one full loop instead of every time the PHP file loads. Thanks for the help.

The path in your check here, if(is_dir('uploads/' . $direc)), will need to be modified the same way.

Thanks to CBroe, the answer was updating the path directory using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. The issue was that whenever a jQuery load function occurs, the path would be updated and no longer be valid.
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\uploads\\";
$directs = scandir($directory);
unset($directs[array_search('.', $directs, true)]);
unset($directs[array_search('..', $directs, true)]);
$dir = array("uploads");

foreach($directs as $direc){
    if(is_dir($directory . $direc)) {
        array_push($dir, $direc);
    }
}

